# creating shortcuts to executables on IRIX64 6.5

Tags: alias, irix

I'm telnetting into an IRIX 64 server and I'm trying to create shortcuts to emacs, gvim, and other executables that are stored in a certain directory. I tried using the `alias` command on the command line in the following manner:

```
alias gvim="/usr/.../gvim"
alias emacs="/usr/.../emacs"
...
```

but whenever I try this and run emacs/gvim, it still doesn't work. And when I run `alias -p`, nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I [found](http://software.majix.org/irix/admin-defaultshell.shtml), IRIX uses csh as its default shell. Thus [its syntax is different](http://www.decf.berkeley.edu/help/unix/csh/aliases.html): rather than `alias foo=bar` you use `alias foo bar`.

Try

```
alias gvim /usr/.../gvim
alias emacs /usr/.../emacs
```

Comment: Oh, ya that works. How do I make it so that my shortcuts will exist every time I start my terminal? Is there some sort of .cshrc or .tcshrc for it?

Comment: You can use `.cshrc`.